# Things to consider when using a Custom Role Provider with IIS6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, roleprovider

I deployed a website on **IIS7.5**. It worked fine.  When I tried to deploy it on **IIS6** I got a **"Configuration Error"** regarding the **CustomRoleProvider**(**Line 65**) .  What seems to be the problem?

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
Line 65: <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="A.B.CustomRoleProvider, A" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" />
      </providers>
 </roleManager>
```

Error Message :

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: What does the exact error message say?

Comment: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" is a TargetInvocationException, I'm guessing that your CustomRoleProvider throws an exception during initialization. Attach a debugger to find the error, or implement a lot of logging to further pin down the offending code.

Comment: @SimonSvensson
`public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)`

config is null; but i dont know why

Comment: :) I've got it; I had a constructor of my own for CustomRoleProvider. I was not calling the base constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="A.B.CustomRoleProvider, CustomRoleProvider.Web.Security" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" />
```